# Is timeStyle.long and .full broken, or have I done something wrong?

Tags: swift, locale, date-format, chinese-locale

I am making an app in swift using Swift UI which uses several different date to string functions and they all seem to work ok for all the locales I've checked besides this one. This works for my home locale of "en_uk" but when I change the schema to be in Traditional Chinese or Brazilian Portuguese both

```
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
```

and

```
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .full
```

do not work. The reason I want these is to include the timeZone. I am aware I can include the timeZone this way.

```
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz")
```

However, this doesn't work in Traditional Chinese or Brazilian Portuguese (and I assume other locales).
Below is the function that seems to be causing the problem.

```
func toStringIncSec(timeZone: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: String(describing: Locale.current))
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
}
```

I am saving the date and timezone like this to a coreData entity.

```
roll.rollcreationdate = Date.now
roll.rollcreationtimeZone = TimeZone.current.identifier
```

In my locale it works as expected and prints **25/07/2023, 23:03:38 BST**

However when changing the schema to Traditional Chinese or Brazilian Portuguese it only prints the date and then crashes the app.

This is how I call the function.

```
roll.rollcreationdate!.toStringIncSec(timeZone: roll.rollcreationtimeZone!)
```

I understand that force unwrapping isn't great but don't believe its an issue here as it works in the UK but not in other locales.

If anyone knows anything please help!!

Comment: It would help to update your question with example of input and output showing correct and inorrect results for given locales.

Comment: The line `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: String(describing: Locale.current))` is certainly wrong. Just use `dateFormatter.locale = .current`. But a date formatter defaults to the current locale so you don't even need to set the locale unless you want something other than the user's current locale.

Comment: You need to point out the exact line that is causing the crash and you need need to include the full error message from the crash. And those force-unwraps are very bad. Handle optionals correctly if you don't want a crash.

Comment: Xcode isn't providing an error message on any line or saying the app crashes but the app won't do anything and the spinning wait cursor appears seemingly indefinitely

Comment: You should set the locale before setting the date and time style

Comment: Thank you, I moved it and it didn't seem to work but now removing it completely did? I don't really know how but thank you for the answer! Without it I would still be very lost! THANKS!

Comment: @miothethis looks like `rollcreationtimeZone` is returning nil for some locales

Comment: Are timezone identifiers dependent on locales? Is it possible to write one for all locales or dependent on the locale you’re in?